# Regular Expression, Update Regex to Allow CIDR Notation with IPV4 Address

Tags: regex

Wondering, if someone could help me add to this regular expression. I've constructed to match valid IP addresses across multiple lines and including whitespace. I just want to add one more piece (CIDR). For example: 10.10.10.10/24. Any knowledge or solution will appreciated. Thank you in advance. Appreciate it!

```
^(((?:(?:\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))[\s?\r?\n?]?)+$
```

Comment: This regex works currently? Can you provide what should/shouldnt match?

Comment: Yes, it works.  Sorry about that. So it matches valid IPs for example 10.10.10.10 ect and will not match something like 256.10.10.10 which is perfect. It will also match them in list form being that the user may input multiple IPs at a time and may list them (press enter after each line) with white space, so thats perfect. I just want to be able to add (CIDR) IPs as a valid match for example (10.10.10.10/24) without breaking what I have. It was tough for me to figure out and construct the right expression before hand.

Comment: Does `^(((?:(?:\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))([\s?\r?\n?]|(/(0|[12]\d|3[0-2])))?)+$` achieve the goal? This adds `/(0|[12]\d|3[0-2]` to the optional ending which I think are the valid CIDR values.

Comment: Yes it did! Thank you so much. Feel like I've learned so much about Regex over the last few days, but still is so tedious and confusing in a lot of ways. Thanks again. Works like a charm.

Comment: For something as common as matching IP addresses, I suggest you find existing code that has already been written, tested and debugged. The kind of numeric validation you are doing is very error-prone.

Answer (score -1):

The CIDR regex for IPV4 is `/(0|[12]\d|3[0-2])`. This can be added to your optional line ending group and should achieve your goal.

```
^(((?:(?:\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))([\s]|(/(0|[12]\d|3[0-2])))?)+$
```

`\s` also should cover `\n` and `\r`.

The `?`s doesn't make characters optional in a character class. A character class lists allowed characters so that would have allowed `?`s as well. One question mark after a character class makes all characters inside optional. `[\s]?` should be the same as `[\s?\r?\n?]?`.